# how to remove all test modules in an existing Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec-rails

I am new to ruby and Ruby on Rails. I used command `rails new [project name]` to create a new rails project, and when using `rails generate scaffold [Model name]` to create a model, rails itself always create a testing module related to the model and the controller. so, how do i remove all rails default testing module and replace with some custom testing modules like `Rspec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have gem `rspec-rails` in your `Gemfile`, and don't have `minitest`, then rails generators already informed that you use Rspec instead of Minitest. `rails generate` command will create specs instead of tests.

Off-topic: it creates fixtures as well. If instead of fixtures you use factories you need to declare it to your config-file:

```
# config/application.rb

config.generators do |g|
  g.factory_bot dir: 'spec/factories'
end
```